# MongoDB insert data after find query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I'm using MongoDB with Mongochef GUI over an Ubuntu Virtual Machine. I need to do a Query which insert the data that I have found previously.

How can i do this? I thought something like this:

```
db.createCollection("prueba", { capped : true, size : 5242880, max : 5000 } )
db.gmap.find( { emotion: 1 } )
db.prueba.insertMany(db.gmap.find( { emotion: 1 } ))
```

GMAP is other collection that i have and the find query returns needed data.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

To solve that we need to store result as an array and then insert - please find snippet below:

```
var a = db.sourceCollection.find().toArray()
db.destinatioCollection.insert(a)
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To exclude some fields use the find **projection** option: in this example the "_id" field is excluded, usefull to insert in the same collection.

To insert many documents use **insertMany** method:

```
db.dstColl.insertMany( db.srcColl.find({}, {"_id": false}).toArray() )
```